# Can i customize a box shadow to be a triangle behind an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying to customize a box shadow to shape like a triangle behind an image. Like  this:[image]

But i don't know if theres a way to doing it using box shadow.

This is my code so far.

```css
#image{
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: -10px 10px  #ff9900;
        }
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/any" id="image" />
```

Comment: Does it need to be a box shadow? I'd use a linear-gradient.

Comment: It does not have to be box-shadow, I just thought that maybe there might be an option that uses it.

Comment: @MrLister that I would combine with a border-image and we have one line of code to add ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple border with gradient will do it and it will be responsive:

```css
#image {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 60%, #ff9900 60.5%) 10;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/180/150/any" id="image" />
<img src="https://placeimg.com/250/150/any" id="image" />
```

Almost the same but with background:

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  padding:10px; /*control the space*/
  background: 
    url(https://placeimg.com/180/150/any) center/cover content-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 60%, #ff9900 60.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the box-shadow property cannot be modeled to be a format different than your father element.

For example, you cannot make a triangle shadow for a square image, like your question.

Try to make a triangle in css and make that with a realative position. Then, use your image with a absolute position.

```css
#triangle-bottomleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-bottomleft"></div>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" title="title of image" alt="alt of image" id="image">
```

I hope this will helpu.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest nesting the triangle and refrain from using `position: absolute;` in this case:

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/150) no-repeat right top;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

#triangle {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 150px solid orange;
  border-right: 200px solid transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

If compatibility with IE is a non-issue you could also use `clip-path`:

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/150) no-repeat right top;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

#triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will try as well.